# How to get stake addresses for a given wallet address in solana-cli?

Tags: solana-cli

I have tried but I don't think there is such thing as `solana account --stakes <wallet address>` to get the list of stakes that belong to the wallet address.

How to get stake addresses for a given wallet address in solana-cli?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stakes` subcommand with the `withdraw-authority` option, ie:

```
$ solana stakes --withdraw-authority <WALLET_PUBKEY>
```